Is it safe to access a raw pointer non atomically, while that pointer is also stored in an atomicptr?
I have a pointer to the UEFI system table, and I am using it in multiple places. The pointer is put into an AtomicPtr, but is also used as a raw pointer after putting it in that AtomicPtr.
main.rs:
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern fn efi_main(image_handle: Handle, system_table: *mut SystemTable) -> Status {
    unsafe {
        UEFIAllocator::init(system_table); // This stores the pointer into a static AtomicPtr 
        clear_screen(system_table);

        println(system_table, b"Hello!");
        // Do some more stuff, some of which involves using `system_table`

allocator.rs
static SYSTEM_TABLE: AtomicPtr<SystemTable> = AtomicPtr::new(ptr::null_mut());

#[global_allocator]
static ALLOCATOR: UEFIAllocator = UEFIAllocator;

pub struct UEFIAllocator;

impl UEFIAllocator {
    /// REQUIRED to be called before ever using the allocator.
    pub fn init(system_table: *mut SystemTable) {
        SYSTEM_TABLE.store(system_table, Ordering::SeqCst);
    }
}

unsafe impl GlobalAlloc for UEFIAllocator {
    unsafe fn alloc(&self, layout: Layout) -> *mut u8 {
        let size = layout.size();
        let align = layout.align();
        let memory_type = MemoryType::LOADER_DATA;


        let boot_services = SYSTEM_TABLE.load(Ordering::Acquire).read().boot_services.read();
        // Do some stuff with `boot_services`

I have noticed that my program always immediately hangs after the second call to write_str. Notably, it does not occur on the second allocation, I can create a bunch of vecs with capacity 1 (I have a qemu print statement that performs no allocation and confirms to me that these vecs are indeed being created and are not optimized away).
Edit: I previously believed that this was caused by multiple calls to write_str, the issue is actually caused by all calls to dealloc. The (likely) reason I believed this was caused by calls to write_str was because it immediately drops it's allocation at the end of it's function block, unlike the test vecs I was creating, which would not be dropped until the end of the efi_main function, which never exits (in my case). The code for dealloc is appended at the end
of this post.
Edit 2: Calling drop manually on the test vecs results in a successful call to dealloc, which fully completes, proving my previous edit incorrect. I do not know what the issue is. Disregard the previous paragraph.
pub struct UEFIDebugOutput {
    system_table: *const SystemTable
}

impl Write for UEFIDebugOutput {
    fn write_str(&mut self, s: &str) -> core::fmt::Result {
        let system_table = unsafe { self.system_table.read() };
        let stdout_handle = system_table.stdout;
        let output_fn = unsafe { stdout_handle.read().output_string };
    
        let mut yoosixteens: Vec<u16> = Vec::with_capacity(s.len()+2);
        s.as_bytes().iter().map(|x| {*x as u16}).collect_into(&mut yoosixteens);
        if yoosixteens.ends_with(&['\n' as u16]) {
            yoosixteens.pop();
            yoosixteens.push('\r' as u16);
            yoosixteens.push('\n' as u16);
        }
        yoosixteens.push(0);
        let _ = unsafe {output_fn(stdout_handle, yoosixteens.as_ptr())};
        Ok(())
    }
}

impl UEFIDebugOutput {
    pub fn new(system_table: *const SystemTable) -> Self {
        UEFIDebugOutput {
            system_table
        }
    }
}

I am unsure of the semantics of how the rust compiler inserts calls to the allocator, and not completely certain of the safety of atomics. I have gone over the Nomicon section on atomics and the atomic documentation in std a few times, and (in the atomic docs) I found something that looks relevant.

Since C++ does not support mixing atomic and non-atomic accesses, or non-synchronized different-sized accesses to the same data, Rust does not support those operations either. Note that both of those restrictions only apply if the accesses are non-synchronized.

let atomic = AtomicU16::new(0);

thread::scope(|s| {
    // This is UB: even reads are not allowed to be mixed
    s.spawn(|| atomic.load(Ordering::Relaxed));
    s.spawn(|| unsafe { atomic.as_ptr().read() });
});


However, this code is creating an atomic, and performing mixed operations on it's contents, but still accessing it "through" the atomic. My code creates an atomic, initalizes it with a null pointer, then stores a pointer to the system table in it, and uses the (non atomic) pointer elsewhere. Is my issue the result of UB from incorrect use of atomics, or something else?
(Note: I realize that all of this is done better with the uefi crate, and not uefi-raw, but I want to gain a better understanding of how things work under the hood.)
    unsafe fn dealloc(&self, mut ptr: *mut u8, layout: Layout) {
        let mut qemu_output: QemuDebugOutput = QemuDebugOutput;
        writeln!(qemu_output, "Freeing!").unwrap();
        let boot_services = SYSTEM_TABLE.load(Ordering::SeqCst).read().boot_services.read();
        if layout.align() > 8 {
            // Retrieve the pointer to the full allocation that was packed right
            // before the aligned allocation in `alloc`.
            ptr = (ptr as *const *mut u8).sub(1).read();
        }
        let status = ((boot_services).free_pool)(ptr);
        if status != Status::SUCCESS {
            panic!("Freeing memory failed! Status: {}", status)
        };
        writeln!(qemu_output, "done freeing!").unwrap();

    }


@eggyal I see. Tell me if I am understanding this correctly. The inner pointer (in this case to the SystemTable) may be freely accessed non-atomically, however, the atomic pointer may not be accessed non-atomically and atomically at once. Since the atomic pointer is always used with calls to .load() and .store(), the issue I am experiencing likely is not due to UB regarding atomic and non atomic accesses. Is that right?

Are you asking us to debug your issue (in which case please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example), or to answer this specific question around atomics?
